# Business Classes for Swift and .Net Web Applications

Tags: .net, swift, business-objects

I want to create business classes and use in the same ones in both a mobile Swift based application and .NET web application using C#.  How do I create them once using C# and use them in both the mobile Swift Application and the .NET web application?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should look into [Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/)

I'm not a huge fan of cross-platform solutions, but given your desire to use C# for iOS development, that is Xamarin's purpose...